# Jquery cannot get value from textbox in joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla

jQuery cannot get value from textbox in Joomla, I'm using the 
script as the follows:

```
<?php JHTML::_('behavior.jquery'); ?>
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function(){

            jQuery("#register").click(function(){


                alert($("#txtusername").val());

            });


    });

</script>

<form name="frm1" id="frm1" method="get">
    <table border="0" style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" align="center">Register</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtusername" id="txtusername"/></td>     
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Password:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtpassword" id="txtpassword"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="button" id="register" value="register"/></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">


            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: are you getting an empty box when alerting, OR are you getting some error in the console.

Comment: I'm not familar with joomla; can you post the generated html (containing the textbox and button)

Comment: I am getting an empty box. please provide solution.

Comment: You haven't really given enough information for anyone to "provide solution"... maybe joomla\you are adding a prefix to the ids... or maybe it's using names not ids. Show us the resulting (from browser) HTML that this jquery is running against and maybe we can help more.

Answer (score 2):

While you using `jQuery.noConflict()`. you can't use `$`

you are alerting value using `$`

```
alert($("#txtusername").val());
```

change this as

```
 alert(jQuery("#txtusername").val());
```

have a look at this working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jdMqK/)